# how to put a single navigation item on the right

Tags: html, css

good day i need help to separate my navigation bar the WELCOME ADMIN should be on the right side here is my code.

HTML

```
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li></ul>
        </li>
   <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">item1</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#" >Welcome Admin</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
  li><a href="#">Subitem Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>


  </nav>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {
background:#000;
width:100%;
margin-top:0px;
height:40px;    
border-radius: 3px; 
    }


    #menu ul ul {
display: none;
    }

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

    #menu ul { 
background: #000
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
float:left;
list-style: none;
margin-top:-20px;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
   }
   }
#menu ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

#menu ul li {
float: left;
    }
#menu ul li:hover {
color:#fff; 
}
 #menu ul li:hover a {
    background:#fff;
color: #000;
   }

#menu ul li a {
display: block; margin-top:20px;
padding:10px 5px;
color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;

 }

#menu ul ul {
 background: #fff;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
top: 80px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
     }
#menu ul ul li {
float: none; 
position: relative;
}
    #menu ul ul li a {
padding: 15px 40px;
color: #fff;
}   

#menu ul ul li a:hover {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
}
```

thankyou for your answers badly need your help for this projects thankyou for those who will answer

Comment: Where are you opening the `<nav>` and where are you closing the `<div id="menu">`?

Comment: the nav is open after the </header> and the <div id ="menu"> is close before ending tag of nav </nav> below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have corrected your css and updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzc4/2/).

**html**

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
    <a href="#">Welcome Admin</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem Three</a> </li>
    </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**css**

```
#menu {
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float:left;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
#menu ul li:hover a {
    background:#fff;
    color: #000;
}
#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding:0 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:40px;
}
#menu ul ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
}
#menu ul li.last {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: again I have corrected something. Please check the same link and up vote if it is ok for you. Thanks.

Comment: sir how can i change the position of the drop down on the right side. i should be indent to the right to see the contents of the dropdown thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the width of the `ul` as 100% otherwise the `float:left` on it collapses the `ul`s width.

The just float the last `li` to the right.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/b2uCF/2/)

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:40px;    
    border-radius: 3px; 
}


#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu ul { 
    background: #000;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:-20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

#menu ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

#menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    color:#fff; 
}
#menu ul li:hover a {
    background:#fff;
    color: #000;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block; margin-top:20px;
    padding:10px 5px;
    color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;

}

#menu ul ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
#menu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   

#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
}

#menu ul li.right {
    float:right;
}
```